# How to read huge CSV file in Mule

Tags: csv, mule, mule-studio

I'am using Mule Studio 3.4.0 Community Edition. 
I have a big problem about how to parse a large CSV file incoming with File Endpoint. The scenario is that I have 3 CSV files and I would putting the files'content into a database. 
But when I try to load a huge file (about 144MB) I get the "OutOfMemory" Exception. I thought as solution to divide/split my the large CSV into smaller size CSVs (I don't know if this solution is the best) o try to find a way to process CSV without throwing an exception.

```
<file:connector name="File" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>

<flow name="CsvToFile" doc:name="CsvToFile">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="src/main/resources/inbox" moveToDirectory="src/main/resources/processed"  responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="CSV" connector-ref="File">
            <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.csv" caseSensitive="true"/>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <component class="it.aizoon.grpBuyer.AddMessageProperty" doc:name="Add Message Property"/>
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="INVOCATION:nome_file=azienda" evaluator="header">
                <jdbc-ee:csv-to-maps-transformer delimiter="," mappingFile="src/main/resources/companies-csv-format.xml" ignoreFirstRecord="true" doc:name="CSV2Azienda"/>
                <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="InsertAziende" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="jdbcConnector" doc:name="Database Azienda">
                    <jdbc-ee:query key="InsertAziende" value="INSERT INTO aw006_azienda VALUES (#[map-payload:AW006_ID], #[map-payload:AW006_ID_CLIENTE], #[map-payload:AW006_RAGIONE_SOCIALE])"/>
                </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>
            </when>
            <when expression="INVOCATION:nome_file=servizi" evaluator="header">
                <jdbc-ee:csv-to-maps-transformer delimiter="," mappingFile="src/main/resources/services-csv-format.xml" ignoreFirstRecord="true" doc:name="CSV2Servizi"/>
                <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="InsertServizi" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="jdbcConnector" doc:name="Database Servizi">
                    <jdbc-ee:query key="InsertServizi" value="INSERT INTO ctrl_aemd_unb_servizi VALUES (#[map-payload:CTRL_ID_TIPO_OPERAZIONE], #[map-payload:CTRL_DESCRIZIONE], #[map-payload:CTRL_COD_SERVIZIO])"/>
                </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>
            </when>
            <when expression="INVOCATION:nome_file=richiesta" evaluator="header">
                <jdbc-ee:csv-to-maps-transformer delimiter="," mappingFile="src/main/resources/requests-csv-format.xml" ignoreFirstRecord="true" doc:name="CSV2Richiesta"/>
                <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="InsertRichieste" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="jdbcConnector" doc:name="Database Richiesta">
                    <jdbc-ee:query key="InsertRichieste" value="INSERT INTO ctrl_aemd_unb_richiesta VALUES (#[map-payload:CTRL_ID_CONTROLLER], #[map-payload:CTRL_NUM_RICH_VENDITORE], #[map-payload:CTRL_VENDITORE], #[map-payload:CTRL_CANALE_VENDITORE], #[map-payload:CTRL_CODICE_SERVIZIO], #[map-payload:CTRL_STATO_AVANZ_SERVIZIO], #[map-payload:CTRL_DATA_INSERIMENTO])"/>
                </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>
            </when>
        </choice>   
    </flow>
```

Please, I do not know how to fix this problem.
Thanks in advance for any kind of help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As SteveS said, the `csv-to-maps-transformer` might try to load the entire file to memory before process it. What you can try to do is split the csv file in smaller parts and send those parts to `VM` to be processed individually.
First, create a component to achieve this first step:

```
public class CSVReader implements Callable{
    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {

        InputStream fileStream = (InputStream) eventContext.getMessage().getPayload();
        DataInputStream ds = new DataInputStream(fileStream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ds));

        MuleClient muleClient = eventContext.getMuleContext().getClient();

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            muleClient.dispatch("vm://in", line, null);
        }

        fileStream.close();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then, split your main flow in two

```
<file:connector name="File" 
    workDirectory="yourWorkDirPath" autoDelete="false" streaming="true"/>

<flow name="CsvToFile" doc:name="Split and dispatch">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="inboxPath"
        moveToDirectory="processedPath" pollingFrequency="60000"
        doc:name="CSV" connector-ref="File">
        <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.csv"
            caseSensitive="true" />
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
    <component class="it.aizoon.grpBuyer.AddMessageProperty" doc:name="Add Message Property" />
    <component class="com.dgonza.CSVReader" doc:name="Split the file and dispatch every line to VM" />
</flow>

<flow name="storeInDatabase" doc:name="receive lines and store in database">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
        path="in" doc:name="VM" />
    <Choice>
        .
        .
        Your JDBC Stuff
        .
        .
    <Choice />
</flow>
```

Maintain your current `file-connector` configuration to enable streaming. With this solution the csv data can be processed without the need to load the entire file to memory first.
HTH

Comment: Thank you very mutch SteveS and Daniel, I'll try this solution.

Comment: Hi, I tried to use your schema but, ALTHOUGH I'am able to insert some hundreds of rows, at one point I get this message:

Comment: INFO  2013-05-07 18:23:18,379 [[splitmultithread].FileSplitter.receiver.02] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: C:\workspace_3.4\splitmultithread\src\main\resources\inbox\richiesta.csv
ERROR 2013-05-07 18:24:00,144 [[splitmultithread].storeInDatabase.stage1.04] org.mule.processor.AsyncWorkListener: Work caused exception on 'workCompleted'. Work being executed was: org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker@3bc752

Comment: What is the value of `pollingFrequency` for your `file:inbound-endpoint`? Try increasing this value. Maybe this endpoint is trying to read the file that is still being processed.

Comment: Yes Daniel, this is the problem. Do you know how to disable the polling or, it should be better, how to trigger the File Endpoint only when there is a file in a directory? And not every x seconds?

Comment: You cannot disable polling for a `file:inbound-endpoint`. To avoid this kind of problems configure a `workDirectory` in the `file:connector`. It will move the file to a different directory before processing it and mule won't try to acquire a lock on it again. Finally, when the stream is closed the file will be moved to the directory configured in the `file:inbound-endpoint`

Comment: Ok, can you post a little example of what you are saying? Just a little piece of code. Thanks Daniel, a lot

Comment: Just doing what you suggested

Comment: Great! Updated my answer adding the connector configuration. If this solved your problem mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have another problem. If I put more than one csv file to be processed mule does not process one file per time...how can I solve this problem? This problem is caused because the system don't wait to process one file and then starts with the other one....I'am getting crazy. Please help me. Your solution works if I have just one csv

Comment: It'll be better if you post another question with this new problem explaining it with more detail

Comment: I solved. If you want to process each file per time you should add the processingStrategy="synchronous" in the CSV to Database flow

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the csv-to-maps-transformer is going to force the whole file into memory. Since you are dealing with one large file, personally, I would tend to just write a Java class to handle it. The File endpoint will pass a filestream to your custom transformer. You can then make a JDBC connection and pick off the information a row at a time without having to load the whole file. I have used [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to parse the CSV for me. So your java class would contain something like the following:

```
protected Object doTransform(Object src, String enc) throws TransformerException {  

    try {
        //Make a JDBC connection here

        //Now read and parse the CSV

        FileReader csvFileData = (FileReader) src;


        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(csvFileData);
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(br);

        //Read the CSV file and add the row to the appropriate List(s)
        String[] nextLine;
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            //Push your data into the database through your JDBC connection
        }
        //Close connection.

               }catch (Exception e){
    }
```

Comment: First of all I would thank you very much for the help, both SteveS and Daniel. I'll try your solution, I hope you'll be here if I'll have some issue. Thank you