# How to stop executing flow reference unless and until the complete batch is finished?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

In my project I am reading a huge tsv file (around 820k) and process the records into db. I have a java file which does validation, after the validation I store the records in a list. Since I can't send the whole list to the vm,I split the list into 2000 and send to the flow. here is how I send 2000 records

```
while(i < validRecords.size()){
                        int j = i + 2000;   

                        if( j < validRecords.size())
                        {                           
                            muleClient.dispatch("vm://validRecordsEtoc", validRecords.subList(i, j), msgProperties);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            muleClient.dispatch("vm://endRecordsEtoc", validRecords.subList(i,validRecords.size()-1), msgProperties);
                        }
                        i = i + 2000;
                    }
```

I have a flow which has reference to a batch and process the records into db.
Here is the flow

```
<flow name="csv-source-inputFlow_Clean_etoc">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="validRecordsEtoc" doc:name="VM_TFO_ETOC_SUBS_SRC"/>
        <enricher doc:name="Enrich inbound Message Properties">
            <logger message="Etoc source message enricher : BatchId : #[message.inboundProperties.flow_batch_id]  Total Records : #[message.inboundProperties.totalRecordCount]  Successful Records : #[message.inboundProperties.successRecordCount]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <enrich source="#[message.inboundProperties.'flow_batch_id']" target="#[flowVars.flow_batch_id]"/>
            <enrich source="#[message.inboundProperties.'flow_source_name']" target="#[flowVars.flow_source_name]"/>
            <enrich source="#[message.inboundProperties.'successRecordCount']" target="#[flowVars.successRecordCount]"/>
            <enrich source="#[message.inboundProperties.'totalRecordCount']" target="#[flowVars.totalRecords]"/>
            <enrich source="#[message.inboundProperties.'input_file_name']" target="#[flowVars.input_file_name]"/>
        </enricher>

        <batch:execute name="csv-source-inputBatch_ETOC" doc:name="csv-source-inputBatch_ETOC"/>

    </flow>
    <batch:job name="csv-source-inputBatch_ETOC">
        <batch:input>
            <set-payload value="#[payload]" doc:name="Set Payload_TFO_ETOC"/>
        </batch:input>
        <batch:process-records>

            <batch:step name="TFOETOC_CLEAN_Batch_Step">
                <batch:commit size="2000" doc:name="TFO_ETOC Clean Batch Commit">
                    <db:insert config-ref="LocalhostPostgres" bulkMode="true" doc:name="Enrich_TFO_ETOC_Src_Data">
                        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO public."csv_tfo_3.4.1 etoc subs"(
            seq_id, batch_id, publication, code, first_name, 
            last_name,subscription_date, email, marketable , 
            organization, department, address1 ,
            address2, city, state,
            zip_code, country, phone, 
            status, source)
 values (DEFAULT,#[flowVars.flow_batch_id],#[payload.Publication] , #[payload.Code] , #[payload.First_Name],#[payload.Last_Name], to_timestamp(#[payload.Subscription_Date],'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),#[payload.Email],#[payload.Marketable],#[payload.Organization],#[payload.Department],#[payload.Address1],#[payload.Address2],#[payload.City],#[payload.State],#[payload.Zip_Code],#[payload.Country],#[payload.Phone],'pending','TFO')]]></db:parameterized-query>



                    </db:insert>
                </batch:commit>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:process-records>

    </batch:job>
```

when I process the last list , i am sending to another flow because i need to call the sub-flow in on complete, where as my last vm gets executed before the previous lists get executed.

I followed the below link

[How to read huge CSV file in Mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395665/how-to-read-huge-csv-file-in-mule)

Can anyone give me any idea how to do that?.

Comment: Please add the other flow which is being called when it is the last batch. "vm://endRecordsEtoc" flow.

Comment: consider using quatrz connector.  you can configure it to use Event Generator Job.

Comment: thank u. It might get work in my case.